# Как правильно описать класс?

Tags: проектирование, оформление, класс

Пишу программу, есть класс треугольник. Так же есть отдельные классы точка(просто две координаты), линия(две точки). Инициализируется объект по координатам, содержит три поля - вершины типа точка. Однако мне необходимо во время работы использовать линии, причем постоянно одни и не же, то есть стороны. Например, чтобы искать периметр, длины сторон, проверять на равнобедренность, и т.д. Вопрос в том, как правильнее оформить класс: добавить три поля типа линия, или каждый раз вычислять их каким либо методом? И вообще, где можно получить информацию как правильно описывать классы?

Comment: лучше вычисляй их методом т.к 3 почти одинаковых поля != хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, будут ли эти линии меняться в дальнейшем у данного объекта. Если у него только конструктор и нет изменений точек, то есть смысл кэшировать вместо постоянного вычисления. Если будут изменения - то тут уже нужно смотреть что выгоднее по ресурсам и удобству - обновлять кэш линий или считать их постоянно. Какого-то единственного подхода нет - везде свои нюансы. И нужно учиться не так, как все пишут, а пониманию зачем они это делают.

Comment: Просто эти линии состоят из тех точек, что уже в полях. То есть получится, что одно поле - это часть другого, то есть кэшируется отдельно линия и ее концы, хотя линия итак содержит в себе эти концы. Получается какая-то избыточность. Не лучше ли тогда кэшировать только линии?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете тогда под линиями и их вычислением? Если точки уже есть, то линии - это просто две точки. Зачем их вычислять? Я ответил исходя из нужды вычислений линий, как вы писали. Если вычислений нет, а только взятие точек всегда, то и хранить линии не нужно. Если всё же линии как отдельные сущности нужны, то может быть польза от их кэширования, несмотря на то, что они повторяют точки. Зависит от задач. Иногда требуется высокая скорость, например при рисовании огромного количества примитивов на холсте, где каждый лишний вызов метода может тормозить общее время и делать много мусора.